# "Limited" internet connection on Windows 7 & 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, internet-connection

My roommate and I are sharing internet with the neighbors and they are using an Airlink router (I'm not sure what brand). I have been able to connect to the internet and it can be really slow since it is being shared between 4 people, and we are using CenturyLink. However, for the first time, my current laptop (windows 8, bigfoot wireless n-1202), my previous laptop (windows 7, some atheros wireless network adapter), and my android phone cannot connect to the internet. Everything works fine using the wifi at school, so I am convinced that the network adapters are not the problem.

What is confusing is that I have been able to connect to the internet before, but now I can't. There are a lot of applications that update automatically which could cause this problem, but how do I find out which ones have updated in the last 2 days? What might I do to diagnose this problem and solve it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: is there an error? can you actually connect to the wifi? or are you connecting fine, but browser times out? what is the err?

Comment: Please bring up a command prompt and type `ping www.google.com` and give us the results of that. We need more details to help you.

Comment: Per the title of the question, Samuel A. seems to be getting a message the connection is "limited". He's already confirmed other WiFi connections work but this one doesn't. Samuel, you might ask your neighbor to restart their router and see if that helps. Also confirm the WiFi key with them, maybe it was accidentally changed.

Comment: If anyone wants to identify the router, be aware that [Airlink 101](http://www.airlink101.com/support/) is a brand name. On their site, you can use the drop down box at the top-right ("Product Quick Find") to browse through their older products. It looks like all of their routers have model numbers that begin with AR.

Comment: I have found that a connection can occur at prohibitive signal levels, in terms of the handshake, but may not 'get out'.  Get closer to the router and see if it makes a difference.  Also, try to rule-out mac-filtering by your neighbour or another security change.

Comment: are you getting ping to router? are you using dynamic DNS?

Comment: Are the neighbors aware that you are "sharing" the connection? I find it exceedingly strange that there is no mention at all of asking the neighbors, who presumably own and control the router, about the situation.

Comment: I previously has problem in one of my laptop telling connection as limited while using tethering from mobile.usually this would happen  if the windows update is incomplete.I got resolved by connecting my lap to high speed network

Answer (score 1):

"Limited" Connection could be a bad gateway or dns.  You are connected to local network but the computer does not know where to go to get the internet.
Set the properties to automatic if they are static. Or maybe delete the existing profile for that wireless ap and create/connect a new profile.

[image]